# how do i access class variable in class methods?

Tags: python, oop

i have been trying to access the this **self.arr** instance in  below methods.
when i call the **main()** it returns the wanted output but when i try call other methods to accessing the same list ,it just returns the empty list

```
class PaginationHelper:

 # The constructor takes in an self.self.array of items and a integer indicating
 # how many items fit within a single page
    def __init__(self, collection, items_per_page):
       self.c = collection
       self.item_per_page = items_per_page
       self.arr = []


    def main(self):
        k = 0
        # i dont kow if below line perfectly creates no. of pages
        count = len(self.c) % self.item_per_page
        
        for i in range(count): # this for loop appends the number of pages " [ ] " in main list
            self.arr.append([])
            
        for x in range(len(self.c)):
            self.arr[k].append(self.c[x]) # now this line fills the pages with items 
            if len(self.arr[k]) >= self.item_per_page:
                k+=1 # when length of the given page exceeds the limit (item_per_page) 
         #then k += 1 means iernate on new page in main list
         
        for z in range(len(self.arr)):
            if len(self.arr[z])<0: self.arr.remove(self.self.arr[z])
        print(self.arr)
    
    def item_count(self):
        print(self.arr)
        return len(self.c) 

    def page_count(self):
        print(self.arr)
        return len(self.arr)
                                                                                                                                                                                                            
  
    def page_item_count(self,page_index):
        pass

    def page_index(self,item_index):
        print(self.arr)
        return len(self.self.arr[item_index])
   
arr = ("a","b","c","d","e","f")

p = PaginationHelper(arr,4)
print(p.page_count())
```

Comment: Fix your indentation. All the methods need to be indented inside the `class`.

Comment: You set `self.arr` to an empty list in `__init__`, you only populate it in the `main` method so it's always empty unless `main` is called

Comment: You never call `p.main()`

Comment: BTW, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks for simpler ways to fill in `self.arr`

Comment: @lianShelvington how do I keep it filled, once populated